# PHP Getting Data From MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, duplicates, connection

I'm trying to get data from my MySQL database with the following PHP code:

```
<?php

$servername = "hostname";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM authors"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    foreach ($stmt as $arr)
    {
        foreach ($arr as $item) 
        {
            echo "$item\n";
        }
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

However this reproduces something that looks like:

"John John Smith Smith"

Instead of my desired output:

"John

Smith"

I have no idea why it is producing duplicates like that.

My end goal is to connect a swift iOS application to this code so that I can easily read the results. Am I going about this the correct way?

Comment: The `$arr` usually contains both numerically indexed and column-named entries ([PDO::FETCH_BOTH](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)). And linebreaks in HTML need more than a plain text `\n` newline.

Comment: You won't be able to see the line break in a browser, instead use HTML `echo "$item<br />";`

Comment: Thanks! This cleared it up